# Swift Singleton not Working

Tags: swift, singleton

Trying to get a Singleton class going in Swift. I'm not getting any errors, but its also just plain not working properly.

Here's the code:

```
// The Singleton class:
class DataWarehouse {
    class var sharedData:DataWarehouse {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance : DataWarehouse? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = DataWarehouse()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    // Here's a variable that I want to pass around to other classes:
    var x = 10 

}
```

Next, I created two classes that can access the value of `x` and use it, change its value, etc:

```
class ClassA {

    var theData = DataWarehouse()

    func changeX() {
        // First, log out the current value of X:
        println("ClassA ==> x is currently: \(theData.x)")

        // Next, change it:
        theData.x = -50
        println("ClassA ==> x was just set to: \(theData.x)")
    }

}
```

Here's the second class - its basically the same as ClassA:

```
class ClassB {

    var theData = DataWarehouse()

    func changeX() {
        // First, log out the current value of X:
        println("ClassB ==> x is currently: \(theData.x)")

        // Next, change it:
        theData.x = -88
        println("ClassB ==> x was just set to: \(theData.x)")
    }

}
```

Finally, in `main.swift` I put the whole thing together:

```
let objectA = ClassA()
objectA.changeX()

let objectB = ClassB()
objectB.changeX()
```

The output I get is:

```
ClassA ==> x is currently: 10
ClassA ==> just set x to: -50
ClassB ==> x is currently: 10
ClassB ==> just set x to: -88
```

So the value of `x` doesn't truly get updated, its always 10.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use this method of singletons, to actually access the singleton you need to use `DataWarehouse.sharedData`, instead of `DataWarehouse()`, when you are 'constructing' the datawarehouse object within the other classes.

At the moment you never actually access sharedInstance.

If you are using Swift 1.2 and prefer, you can use some cleaner text with class constants (lazy initialised):

```
class Singleton {

    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()

    init() {
        println("Hello");
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't have anything called `DataWarehouse.sharedInstance` - I think you meant `DataWarehouse.sharedData` ?  Either way, I tried your shorter version (I am indeed using Swift 1.2) - it works.  And its quite interesting. I'm so used to calling a Constructor with `()`, but here we're accessing a property of the class (`sharedInstance`) - and **it** does the instantiating. Kinda loopy :-)  But I get it, its a static allocation, and it works - very cool. Thanks!

Comment: Woops typo (i generally call it sharedInstance) I will amend my answer!

Comment: correct answer, but you should also make the init() method private (it defaults to public)

Answer (score 0):

As above but make the init private, so that instances are forced to use the sharedInstance

```
class Singleton {
   static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
   private init() {
      // Only methods within the class can access here
   }
}
```

Then

```
let single = Singleton() // Is not allowed by the compiler
```

You have to use

```
let single = Singleton.sharedInstance
```